# Magento Paypal issues with base currency AED

Tags: paypal, ce-1.9.0.1

I am using magento 1.9.0.1 CE version. If i am using base currency is USD paypal appear on the Checkout page.BUt If i am using base currency is AED payapl does not appear on the Checkout page.

Is there any way in Magento where I can integrate Paypal with base currency AED

Answer (score 2):

Check this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916361/magento-paypal-issues-with-base-currency-inr

Add the currency AED to the array.
It will work.

Answer (score 0):

This **FREE** Magento Extension that supports PayPal payments for not supported currencies by PayPal might be helpful for you.

https://github.com/Meabed/Paypal-Multi-Currency-Magento

**Detailed answer here:** [paypal express checkout for AED currency](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79071/paypal-express-checkout-for-aed-currency)