# paypal express checkout for AED currency

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, currency

My base currency is AED. But as per [paypal supported currencies](https://www.paypal.com/multicurrency) I cant pay in AED. So, I converted the currency to USD and changing the currency code to USD.

Now I can able to reach paypal with currency code as USD and converted currency. After competing payment I am being redirected to `paypal/express/return/` Frmo `returnAction` forwarded to `Paypal\Model\Express\Checkout.php` but after executing the line `$service->submitAll()` in the method `place` i am getting error as below

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. The transaction currency
>   specified must be the same as previously specified (#10444:
>   Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional
>   error messages for details).

Unable to understand whats happening `$service->submitAll()`

Comment: Maybe the two amounts differ? I mean, the order in Magento is placed in AED, and the order in Paypal is place in USD. When Paypal checks the order amount, it has two different sums.

Answer (score 2):

This **FREE Magento Extension** that supports PayPal payments for not supported currencies by PayPal might be helpful for you.

https://github.com/Meabed/Paypal-Multi-Currency-Magento

First of all, we need to setup multi-currency shop (`System -> Configuration -> GENERAL -> Currency Setup`).

[image]

Then, we do necessary setup for PayPal Payment Method (`System -> Configuration -> SALES -> Payment Methods`).

[image]

After installing this module, you can go to `System -> Configuration -> SALES -> Payment Methods -> Paypal Multi Currency` and make necessary settings over there.

[image]

Here is the checkout page where you can see USD equivalent amount being displayed on `Order Review` step.

[image]

Finally, after the order is placed, the following information is displayed in `Sales -> Orders` in Magento admin/backend.

[image]

***PS:*** The images above are taken from the extension's github.

Comment: In magento1.9 community edition paypal standard has been removed. So I am using paypal express. I tried this extension with CE version. But not working, :-(

Comment: One good thing is This extension is working fine with paypal standard available in magento1.7 CE. :-)

Comment: I checked this insert thing on one of your other post in MSE. i asked a question on that also. I cant find any record on core_config_data. Regarding insert the record back can you please view your today's recent message and reply?

Comment: You can delete and add new comment

Comment: @version.beta I am using Magento 1.9 CE. Paypal standard is not removed in it. I think you are having issue with Paypal standard as mentioned here: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-paypal-standard-payment-form-replaced-by-paypal-express-checkout-form-in-admin-payment-settings/